# Filter only users who belong to something in 3rd table

Tags: mysql, sql

these are my tables:

TABLE 'USERS'

```
ID      NAME     AGE 
01      John     22
02      Gloria   27
```

TABLE 'CITIES'

```
ID    USER_ID    CITY
22    01         Sacramento
23    02         Phoenix
```

TABLE 'HOBBIES'

```
ID     USER_ID   HOBBY
88     01        swimming
89     01        reading
90     02        reading
```

Okay, so we have two fellas: John is from Sacramento and likes swimming and reading. 
Gloria is from Phoenix and only likes reading.

I know how to join the first two tables:

```
SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN cities ON users.id = cities.user_id
```

But how can I join the 'hobbies' table and only display users who like swimming?

Thanks a lot, 
Matthias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will just add a `JOIN` to the last table and add a `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT * 
FROM users  
INNER JOIN cities  
    ON users.id = cities.user_id
INNER JOIN hobbies
    ON users.id = hobbies.USER_ID
WHERE Hobbies.Hobby = 'swimming'
```

Comment: I couldn't have said it better myself!

Answer (score 1):

Keep joining and filter the results:

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM users 
INNER JOIN cities ON users.id = cities.user_id 
INNER JOIN hobbies ON users.id = hobbies.user_id
WHERE hobbies.hobby = 'swimming'
```

Answer (score 0):

select u.id, u.name, c.city, h.hobby 
from users u 
inner join cities c 
on u.id=c.id
inner join hobbies h 
on u.id = h.id
where to_lower (h.hobby) = 'swimming'